# java foreach changes elements

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I try to use `for` and `foreach` loops to print my sorted array. But i see, that the `for` and `foreach` loops print different values of the same array. I can not understand what I'm doing wrong?

Code below:

```
import java.util.Random;

class ArraysTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myArray = new int[20];
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.println("*** Unsorted array ***");

        // filling myArray by random int values
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myArray[i] = (rand.nextInt(i+1));
            System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
        } System.out.println("\n");

        // sorting myArray
        java.util.Arrays.parallelSort(myArray);

        System.out.println("*** Sorted array \"for-loop\" ***");
        // printing values in console with for-loop 
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
        } System.out.println("\n");

        System.out.println("*** Sorted array \"foreach-loop\" ***");
        // printing values in console with foreach-loop
        for(int j : myArray) {
            System.out.print(myArray[j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is console out:

```
*** Unsorted array ***
0 1 1 3 3 1 5 1 7 4 2 0 6 11 0 3 7 0 3 17

*** Sorted array "for-loop" ***
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 7 11 17

*** Sorted array "foreach-loop" ***
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 3 7
```

Comment: In the second for, j is a value not a index, try to print just j:
System.out.print(j + " ");

Comment: Yeah, It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing the jth element of myArray, when in fact j is the number you wish to print.

```
for(int j:myArray){
    System.out.print(j + " ");
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks)

Answer (score 3):

```
    System.out.println("*** Sorted array \"foreach-loop\" ***");
    // printing values in console with foreach-loop
    for(int j : myArray) {
        System.out.print(myArray[j] + " "); <---
    }
```

The problem is in this line, where you're getting the element from the array, `j`, but instead of printing it, you're using it access the array again. Your print statement should be

```
System.out.print(j + " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in your for-each loop you are printing the value at index `j` and what you want to print is actually the value that the variable `j` has. So replace this:

```
for(int j : myArray) {
    System.out.print(myArray[j] + " ");
}
```

with this:

```
for(int j : myArray) {
    System.out.print(j + " ");
}
```